# How can I understand the operation of this scale selector for current measurements on the Power Profiler Kit?

Tags: current-measurement

I'm reviewing the design of the Power Profiler Kit II, generously provided by Nordic [here](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-hardware/Power-Profiler-Kit-2/Download#infotabs), specifically the auto-scale selection stage for measuring current, the first stage being this:

[image]

I manage to understand it, the current flows through the mosfet then the resistor and returns to external GND or internal GND. However, this stage:

[image]

I can't quite grasp it. I know that the instrumentation amplifier amplifies the measurement across the resistors, also that the op-amps seem to be functioning as comparators (I think), and that there are resistive dividers that are 'probably' powered by the output of the previous op-amp. But I really can't understand how this works to correctly turn on the P-MOS and measure at the necessary scale. Could someone help me understand this, please?